# How to populate multidimensional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm getting a `Use of uninitialized value` error. I don't know if I'm populating my multidimensional array correctly.

```
my @matrix;

for (my $i=1; $i<=3;$i++){
    $matrix[$i][0] = 4;
}
for (my $j=1; $j<=3;$j++){
    $matrix[0][$j] = 4;
}

print $matrix[0][0];
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. The way I wrote it, the matrix is supposed to populate like so:

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
```

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@matrix;` Please check http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS

Comment: PS, `for my $i (1..3)` is far cleaner and more efficient than `for (my $i=1; $i<=3;$i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're populating `$matrix[1][0]` and `$matrix[0][1]`, but you don't store anything in `$matrix[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl arrays start at 0 - try

```
my $i = 0
```